# How to find shortest path in O(mn)

Tags: shortest-path

Given a `matrix A` with size `(n*m)`,we have `aij=1` or `aij=0` for all i,j, if `aij=1` we call it "black",else "white", The distance between two points `p(i,j)` and `q(k,l)` is defined as below:
        `d(p,q)=|i-k|+|j-l|`.

Is there any Algorithm run in time `O(mn)` to find a white point and its nearest black point for all white points?

```
dp1[i][j] = min(dp1[i-1][j], dp1[i][j-1],dp[i-1][j-1]+1)+1 if A[i][j]=1 else 0
dp2,dp3,dp4 are similar

res[i][j] = min(dp1[i][j], dp2[i][j], dp3[i][j], dp4[i][j])
here are my code, I cannot guarantee correctness
```

Comment: I find the language in the question confusing. Do you mean "Is there any algorithm with runtime O(mn) that finds, for all white points i,j, the black point nearest to i,j?"? And if so, what does that have to do with "shortest path"?

Comment: Yes! You have a better expression than me.

Answer (score 1):

I think we are in the same university.
I think Yong Yan's answer is not correct. Your answer can only cover black's up,bottom, left and right, if the white's up, bottom, left and right has no black, it will be get wrong shortest distance.

This is my answer:

```
dp1[i][j] = min(dp1[i-1][j], dp1[i][j-1])+1 if A[i][j]=1 else 0
dp2[i][j] = min(dp2[i-1][j], dp2[i][j+1])+1 if A[i][j]=1 else 0
dp3[i][j] = min(dp3[i+1][j], dp3[i][j-1])+1 if A[i][j]=1 else 0
dp4[i][j] = min(dp4[i+1][j], dp4[i][j+1])+1 if A[i][j]=1 else 0

res[i][j] = min(dp1[i][j], dp2[i][j], dp3[i][j], dp4[i][j])
```

Comment: I have the same answer with you ,but  I check three different ways in Bellman equation